# (2014?) Proposal of an alternative referendum form in Crimea and Donbass under the supervision of the UN / OSCE

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, united-nations, referendum, osce

I'm trying to find out if there were (official) proposals* to hold alternative forms of referendums in the two areas. I know that the UN and OSCE have criticized and not recognized the referenda that were planned and held, and I can find sources to that effect.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any information on alternative proposals that may have been made. I do not necessarily want to draw the conclusion that they did not exist.

Therefore my question, whether there were these suggestions. I would be additionally grateful for corresponding evidence/sources.

---

*e.g. foreign ministry, EU, UN etc. in the sense of "let's do a referendum, but do it right"

Comment: The world is full of proposals. Without narrowing this down, there's always "that guy" at the pub who proposed something similar. In fact, a lot of the Qs here about this conflict are little more than "who else agrees with me on <this issue>?"

Comment: I don't know of any such proposals, and I suspect that there weren't any official ones, since (as I understand it) even the _concept_ of a referendum to decide to join Russia was illegal under Crimea's existing laws.

Comment: @Bobson Yes, me too. But i think it's risky to make that conclusion, so i had to ask.

Comment: The largest alternative was basically not to make any referendum at all.

Comment: Is this asking about international proposals?  or Russia-originated proposals?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica mostly international, but russia-originated is interesting as well

Answer (score 6):

Having a regional secession referendum is typically quite a problematic affair and - in normal conditions - carried with the, perhaps grudging, permission of the country it is taking place in.

For example, see Scotland or Quebec.  Or New Caledonia.  As a counterexample, see the unrecognized Catalan referendum (which perhaps Spain reacted somewhat too harshly to - they've recently dropped charges on the politicians involved IIRC).

**So, in order for international institutions to have *seriously* considered recognizing and supervising this referendum, it would have first been up to Ukraine to say "yes, you can hold a referendum in Crimea about leaving".**

And, if Crimea, why not hold similar referenda in Russia?  Chechnya, perhaps?  Oddly as well, Russia only seems to like referenda when it suits them:  [Kosovo independence referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_Kosovan_independence_referendum)

---

Re. Kosovo.  It seceded near the end of the Yugoslav Wars, where genocidal acts had been carried out, by Serbia and its allies. Milosevic went to a war crimes tribunal because of his behavior there. So, *at least from the PoV of the countries which recognized it*, Kosovo is not the same thing as putting as a condition that UA, and RU, first to agree to referenda before holding them on their territory.  *If today, another Serbian region wanted to hold a departure referendum, I'd be extremely surprised if the international community - and that includes countries recognizing Kosovo - didn't tell them to get Serbia's permission first.*

Comment: I'm not sure why you assume that Chechnya would want out. Starting with Chechnya having no "out", i.e. no road or port to anything that is not Russia.

Comment: Hmmm, the events of 1994 and 2000, maybe?  I mean, let's say you're right, an honest, supervised, referendum should be OK with Russia, neh?  Or is this holding referenda a one-way street, only good when it suits Russia?

Comment: The events of 1994 and 2000 do not change geography and economics. Countries tend to not carry secession referendums out of blue.

Comment: Like I said, then no problem holding a referendum there, no?  [Good for the gander, good for the goose](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what's%20good%20for%20the%20goose%20is%20good%20for%20the%20gander).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Kadyrov will be able to show 99% for anything he wants to be voted, including a referendum to join Japan. Would you really be happier with another one of "Russian Federation voting" happening with expected result?

Comment: This is a fair point and frame challenge, but I'm not sure it's actually answering the Q. Political movements often enough call for (and sometimes even organize) referendums without getting said central approval. I mean Kosovo is also an example in that regard...

Comment: We obviously cannot say what the result of such referendum may be, if it requires a movement to exist which just isn't there currently, and its properties are not known.

Comment: @Fizz **I am saying we are unlikely to see any *serious* consideration by OSCE or the like to monitor a referendum.  Evidence of absence and all that.**  For the reasons I give in this A. *in normal conditions* above is precisely meant to cover Kosovo.  If you recall, Kosovo seceded end of the Yugoslav Wars, where genocidal acts had been carried out, by Serbia and its allies.  Milosevic went to a war crimes tribunal because of his behavior, in Kosovo.  So, no, Kosovo is not the same thing as expecting UA, and RU, to first to agree to referenda before holding them on their territory.

Comment: Like I said in a comment under the Q, I find the threshold "is anyone calling for" somewhat weak. Some people call for unrealistic things to happen; even politicians sometimes do this for grandstanding etc. That you're basically answering another question, like whether OSCE would give *serious* consideration to such calls (per your emphasis) is another matter.

Comment: @alamar Chechnya has a border with Georgia.

Comment: There's the height of Caucasus mountains there, and no road @Acccumulation

Answer (score 3):

I remember this idea entertained by so-called non-coopted Russian opposition - that's mostly pro-western liberal media crowd (Navalny, Meduza, TV Rain) as opposed to Duma parties such as CPRF or LDPR. Some alternative referendum in Crimea was supposed to be a way to resolve the Crimean question in post-Putin Russia.

I believe they expected [Novorossiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novorossiya_(confederation)) to go away either via Minsk accords or unilaterally, but for some reason they expected Western-recognized re-referendum in Crimea to be possible.

[Example](https://medialeaks.ru/navalnyjkrymnash/):

> Навальный считает, что население Крыма должно подтвердить свое решение о вхождении в состав России на «нормальном референдуме», но при этом признает, что полуостров теперь российский и уже не вернется в состав Украины.

> Navalny believes that the population of Crimea should confirm its decision to join Russia during "real referendum", but at the same time recognizes that the peninsula is now Russian and will not return to Ukraine.

Well, it turns out we've got post-liberal Russia before we had post-Putin Russia, because the people in question are, en masse, no longer in Russia.

Comment: Is it possible to also find a source with exact wordings for the thing you remember? That would be great.

Comment: "but for some reason": The rather plausible reason was that Russia had organized/recognized the Crimean referendum at that point, but for a long time the Kremlin didn't formally enjoin the union-with-Russia referendums in DNR/LPR. Or even granted formal recognition to these as independent countries, until 2022 that is.

Comment: What *is* implausible here is that the West, and especially Ukraine, was going to recognize the Russian Crimea after this-referendum or that-referendum.

Comment: It would help very much if you spelled out and explained the acronyms CPRF, LDPR, and LDNR. As is, this answer is a bit unreadable.

Comment: I would provide a link for the latter, but if you don't know what it stands for, my answer is a poor place to get a first impression.

Comment: @David Hammen CPRF stands for Communist Party of Russian Federatio, LDPR was an acronym of Liberal Democratic Party of Russia and LDNR should be LDPR which is a mix of LPR and DPR.